# How to import custom file types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-loader, .d.ts

As a bit of a fun project, I'm making a "framework" for creating native web components. I've created a webpack loader that parses some XML in custom `.comp` files and exports an es2015 class. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to import these `.comp` files in my typescript files.

I've tried importing my custom files in a regular javascript file, and everything works as expected; I can see the loader I created running, and I get the expected output. But when I try to import in a typescript file I just get the error `Cannot find module 'test/test.comp'`. I tried creating an empty declaration file and noticed the error message changes to `File '[path]/test/test.d.ts' is not a module`

Here's my webpack config:

```javascript
mode: 'development',
watch: true,
entry: './test/main.js',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.comp/,
            use: path.resolve(__dirname, 'core/compose-loader.js'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.comp'],
    alias: {
        'core': path.resolve(__dirname, "core/"),
        'test': path.resolve(__dirname, "test/")
    }
}
```

And my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "core": ["core/*"],
            "test": ["test/*"]
        },
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": ["./core"]

    },
    "include": [
        "test/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "core",
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.comp"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can define the types for all these files with `*.comp` in a `declarations.d.ts` file (or whatever name you choose).

```js
declare module "*.comp" {
  const value: any; // Add better type definitions here if desired.
  export default value;
}
```

You may need to also add this to `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Other configuration...
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/declarations.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

And now, `import value from "./test.comp"` should work as expected (at least the types).

Note: for VSCode the definition file should not be higher in the folder structure than the import.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your reply. It's working now, albeit not quite in the manner I had hoped. At the project root, I have three folders: core, test, and build. I've been trying to run my tests from a `test.ts` file inside the test directory. Your solution worked once I moved my test file outside the test directory into the project root. Is there any way I could get it working from inside the testing folder?

Comment: I cam here looking for:
```
[tsl] TS2307: Cannot find module './typeDefs/a.gql' or its corresponding type declarations.
```
while working with `apollo-server`, `webpack` and `typescript`. The code was working as `webpack` was loading everything but the `ts-loader` was throwing this annoying error.

The `typeRoots` part was not needed and just the `declaration` helped.

Comment: I cannot do something like this to define too many declaration file: `"typeRoots": [ "**/*.d.ts" ]` I also tried this one `"types": [ "**/*.d.ts" ]` but they does not work. I have many `.d.ts.` files and some of them are defined globally.

Comment: this works but how about if we want to support better initillisense support e.g - file might expose different methods and different files expose different methods. Is there any way to emit dynamic export.

Comment: Is it possible to do `:string as const`?

Comment: @KevinGhadyani - are  you looking to do `const value: string;` to say the exported value is a `string`?

Comment: I was hoping the exported value would be the value in the file itself, but don't worry about it. Apparently, I was completely wrong with my approach. You need to convert `.graphql` files to `.ts` to be able to import them properly as a `const` string.