# Angular import file with custom extension from assets folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I have a service that imports some data.
This file has a custom extension.
So I'm doing this to import it:

```
import mydata from '../../assets/file.my-ext';
```

Typescript is giving me this:

```
'mydata' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Cannot find module '../../assets/file.my-ext' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149937/how-to-import-custom-file-types-in-typescript) ... please

Comment: You'll need to have a custom webpack configuration that loads files that are beyond the angular configuration. Try https://developapa.com/angular-custom-webpack-configuration/ maybe there is an example there for gif